# How to send JSON data created by Python to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python, html, json, cherrypy

I am using Python `cherrypy` and `Jinja` to serve my web pages. I have two Python files: *Main.py* (handle web pages) and *search.py* (server-side functions).
I create a dynamic dropdown list (using `JavaScript`) based on a local `JSON` file called *component.json*(created by function *componentSelectBar* inside *search.py*).

I want to ask how can my JavaScript retrieve JSON data **without physically storing the JSON data into my local website root's folder** and still fulfil the function of dynamic dropdown list.

The *componentSelectBar* function inside *search.py*:

```
def componentSelectBar(self, brand, category):
    args = [brand, category]
    self.myCursor.callproc('findComponent', args)
    for result in self.myCursor.stored_results():
        component = result.fetchall()
    if (len(component) == 0):
        print "component not found"
        return "no"

    components = []
    for com in component:
        t = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', com[0]).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
        components.append(t)

    j = json.dumps(components)
    rowarraysFile = 'public/json/component.json'
    f = open(rowarraysFile, 'w')
    print >> f, j

    print "finish component bar"
    return "ok"
```

The *selectBar.js*:

```
    $.getJSON("static/json/component.json", function (result) {
        console.log("retrieve component list");
        console.log("where am i");
        $.each(result, function (i, word) {
            $("#component").append("<option>"+word+"</option>");
        });
    });
```

Comment: Basically, you need a handler to be marked with @cherrypy.tools.json_out decorator returning dict/list. Just change the URL in JS, and that's it. 
Your question currently contains too many information, which doesn't look related to the problem. Please, consider reducing its size and providing only minimum amount of code to not confuse readers.

Answer (score 0):

1. store results from componentSelectBar into database
2. expose new api to get results from database and return json to browser

demo here:

```
@cherrypy.expose
def codeSearch(self, modelNumber, category, brand):
    ...
    result = self.search.componentSelectBar(cherrypy.session['brand'], cherrypy.session['category'])
    # here store result into a database, for example, brand_category_search_result
    ...

@cherrypy.expose
@cherrypy.tools.json_out()
def getSearchResult(self, category, brand):
    # load json from that database, here is brand_category_search_result
    a_json = loadSearchResult(category, brand)

    return a_json
```

document on CherryPy, hope helps:
[Encoding response](http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/basics.html#encoding-response)

In your broswer, you need to GET /getSearchResult for json:

```
$.getJSON("/getSearchResult/<arguments here>", function (result) {
    console.log("retrieve component list");
    console.log("where am i");
    $.each(result, function (i, word) {
        $("#component").append("<option>"+word+"</option>");
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

To use that json data directly into javascript you can use

```
var response = JSON.parse(component);
console.log(component); //prints
```

OR

You already created json file.If that file is in right format then you can read json data from that file using jQuery `jQuery.getJSON()` For more: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: Yeah, you are correct. I can use the local JSON file, and it works fine. But now I want to improve the process, I mean I do not want to store the JSON file locally, and the JavaScript can still retrieve my JSON data from Python. Something like `return json.dumps(components)`, but I do not know how to implement it with JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

You are rendering a HTML and sending it as response. If you wish to do with JSON, this has to change. You should return JSON in your main.py, whereas you will send a HTML(GET or POST) from Javascript and render it back.

```
def componentSelectBar(self, brand, category):
    /* Your code goes here */
    j = json.dumps(components)
    // Code to add a persistent store here
    rowarraysFile = 'public/json/component.json'
    f = open(rowarraysFile, 'w')
    print >> f, j
    // Better to use append mode and append the contents to the file in python
    return j //Instead of string ok


@cherrypy.expose
def codeSearch(self):
    json_request = cherrypy.request.body.read()
    import json # This should go to the top of the file
    input_dict = json.loads(json_request)
    modelNumber = input_dict.get("modelNumber", "")
    category = input_dict.get("category", "")
    brand = input_dict.get("brand", "")
    /* Your code goes here */
    json_response = self.search.componentSelectBar(cherrypy.session['brand'], cherrypy.session['category'])
    return json_response
```

Here, I added only for the successful scenario. However, you should manage the failure scenarios(a JSON error response that could give as much detail as possible) in the `componentSelectBar` function. That will help you keep the `codeSearch` function as plain as possible and help in a long run(read maintaining the code).

And I would suggest you to read [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and apply it to the code as it is kind of norm for all python programmers and help any one else who touches your code.

EDIT: This is a sample javascript function that will make a post request and get the JSON response:

```
searchResponse: function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/codeSearch', // Add your URL here
    data: {"brand" : "Levis", "category" : "pants"}
    async: False, 
    success: function(search_response) {
      response_json = JSON.parse(search_response)
      alert(response_json)
      // Do what you have to do here;
      // In this specific case, you have to generate table or any structure based on the response received
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Sorry I still do not know how to using this JSON data in JavaScript after I return the JSON data in _main.py_. Would you mind show me how to use the return JSON data in JavaScript to create the dynamic dropdown list?

Comment: Sure. I will update the answer with a sample JS function that will get the JSON data :)

Comment: Added a sample JS function. By this way, you will receive the JSON response. But then, you have to render it with JavaScript to display the output in required format.

Comment: If I return `json_response` in my `main.py`, I won't be able to load my web page, right? Instead, the JSON data will appear, which is not what I want.